# KnockoutJS - Mapping plugin

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Im using the mapping plugin with Knockout which is great, makes it very easy for me.

However what if I want to perform a set of operations on a value prior to it being pushed out to the view?

Say I'm getting a 'date' string back from a REST call, I can reference that in my view using the mapping plugin by doing viewModel.date....

However what if I wanted to edit the data string prior to it being passed to the mapping plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping plugin receives a JSON string.  As long as your edits don't change the structure, it has no problem.
I do exact operations you describe.  When data is returned from my Ajax call, I modify the received date strings before sending into the mapping plugin.